# How are housenumbers and streets linked in a OSM based PostGIS DB?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I'm trying to understand how OSM is linking housenumbers and streets with each other. I downloaded an osm file for germany and imported it into a PostGIS DB.
To understand how the linking is working I just took a street with a housenumber and exported it as xml from osm.org.
I opened the xml file and saw the entry for the housenumber and the street and it looked like this:

```js
<way id="141827749" user="MichaH" uid="8464" visible="true" version="1" changeset="10149457" timestamp="2011-12-18T18:41:33Z">
 <nd ref="1005720791"/>
 <nd ref="1552517039"/>
 <nd ref="1552517025"/>
 <nd ref="1005720152"/>
 <nd ref="1005720791"/>
 <tag k="addr:city" v="Frankfurt"/>
 <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="16"/>
 <tag k="addr:postcode" v="60326"/>
 <tag k="addr:street" v="Wörsdorfer Straße"/>
 <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
</way>
```

Obviously I took the id=141827749 and found one entry in planet_osm_ways.
Result:

```
id        | nodes                                                    | tags
141827749 | {1005720791,1552517039,1552517025,1005720152,1005720791} | {building,yes,addr:housenumber,16}
```

So I got the housenumber. But where is the street name? When I search the tags for the street name i get 3 entries pointing to other nodes. The correct entry for it is as I know (because its a residential area):

```
id      | nodes                                                                                                                  | tags
6235469 | {52082395,1552517028,1552516972,1552516886,1552516856,1552516836,1552516769,1552516705,1552516652,1552516571,52082405} | {oneway,yes,name,"Wörsdorfer Straße",highway,residential}
```

But where is the link between all this? Does anybody know? I didnt find any info on the OSM wiki pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the data has been imported. Looking at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema it looks like you should be using `planet_osm_line` or `planet_osm_roads` since planet_osm_ways is temporary. However, if the names were not specified to be included as a tag on the import (unlikely) it could be that they are not being imported into the database. You'll have to specify **how** the xml was imported into the database, because there are a large number of different ways of doing it.

The nature of OSM means that there is no de-facto standard for translating the xml file into a database schema, although there are several common ways of doing it, facilitated by software.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can i know how my osm2pgsql script worked? I used the tutorial i found on the OSM wiki page. I remember it took me a lot of time to get this PostGIS thing running. Had to install different apps by source and compile to get it running. but at the end i just called osm2pgsql on the OSM file to import my stuff. can you tell me if there is any site telling about the different schemas that can be used you were talking about. i think i need more info about this to understand. thanks.

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what version of osm2pgsql you used, what extract you used and therefore what you results you should expect. Maybe start a new question with all these details, exactly what you did and what results you got, and why you are confused. You don't say if you looked in planet_osm_line for instance. You may find the various OSM help channels have more people familiar with their tools.

Answer (score 2):

The "associatedStreet" relation links streets and buildings/ways together: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:associatedStreet